# XMLDocument compared to another file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a document in memory of type XmlDocument and a file loaded from a directory that is an xml file.  I would like to compare these the fastest way possible.

Currently this is how I am doing it...but this is a hash and is not as fast as byte for byte.  I would like to revise this to be byte by byte..but would like to check for anything that may speed this up....such as a quick length comparison.  I am not sure if I can check length since one is in memory and the other is loaded from a file.  The file names are always the same..so I cannot check that.

```
protected bool AreFilesTheSame(XmlDocument doc, string fileToCompareTo)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileToCompareTo))
            return (false);

        try
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptNewPub = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml.ToCharArray());
            cryptNewPub.ComputeHash(xmlBytes);

            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptOldPub = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToCompareTo);
            cryptOldPub.ComputeHash(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();

            if (cryptNewPub.Hash.Length != cryptOldPub.Hash.Length)
                return (false);

            for (int i = 0; i < cryptNewPub.Hash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (cryptNewPub.Hash[i] != cryptOldPub.Hash[i])
                    return (false);
            }

            return (true);
        }
        catch
        {
            return (false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply loading contents of file to compare to in a string, and then simply comparing that string to `doc.OuterXml`.  This should be faster than computing hashes on both.

Comment: Do you need byte comparison, text comparison (ignore encoding differences) or XML comparison (ignore formatting and namespace prefixes)?

Comment: I think byte comparison is all.  Basically its xml files being created in memory...and it checks the previously created xml files which now are on the drive..to see if they are different before writing.  The file names would be the same even if the data is different.  I would think its possible the length could be the same and it be a different file.  Do not care about the structure of the xml.  Just basically a byte compare to determine if it needs to overite the file...true or false answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to load the second XML file and compare the OuterXML:

```
    protected bool AreFilesTheSame(XmlDocument doc, string fileToCompareTo)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileToCompareTo))
            return (false);

        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load(fileToCompareTo);

            return doc.OuterXml == doc2.OuterXml;
        }
        catch
        {
            return (false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just need to know at the fastest approach to see if there is anything different in the file.  It could be anything..if the file is different I need to recognize that.  The fact that its XML does not matter other than thats how the files are loaded up..one as a filestream and the other as an xmldocument ....but comparing xml to xml seems slower than byte for byte....how do you load up the two and just do a byte for byte comparison....

Comment: Since they are XML, the byte content may be different, while the XML content is the same. Loading both into memory, and comparing them as a string **is** a byte-for-byte comparison, and ensures that inconsequential bytes like whitespace are ignored.